# EF Code First alter default Initial Catalog

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando modificar o banco de dados `Padrão` do `Entity Framework` porém o 
`Initial Catalog` não está sendo modificado.

[image: Events - Visual Studio 15]

[image: Web.config]

Comment: Você poderia compartilhar conosco a seção `connectionStrings` do seu web.config?

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="VitecStore" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VitecStore;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  
  </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 0):

Teste com a seguinte Connection String:

```
<add name="VitecStore" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VitecStore;database=VitecStore;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```